# How to get row count of 2 different tables (and databases) in one query?

Tags: mysql, count, rows

I got a database named `accounts` and `account` table inside of this database, Also I got the database named `players` and `player` table inside of this database.

How can I get a rows count of this two tables in one query?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(`account`.`account`.`id`) AS 'accounts',
    SUM(`player`.`player`) AS 'players';
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need exactly rows count (not sum), than do something like this:

```
select
(select count(*) from accounts.account) as count1,
(select count(*) from players.player) as count2
```

or

```
select count(*) as `count`,"account" as `table` from accounts.account
union all
select count(*) as `count`,"player" as `table` from players.player
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `UNION` operation on two select statements will do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Accounts' FROM Accounts.Account
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 'Players' FROM Players.Player
```

And you have to qualify each table with the database name since they're in separate databases.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(`account`.`id`) AS 'accounts',
   COUNT(`player`.`player`) AS 'players'
FROM
   `account`,
   `player`
```

Comment: Getting this message: `SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT Id 
    FROM accounts.account 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT player 
    FROM players.player ) AS BothTables
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with Value (nbr, name ) as
(
select count(*) amount, 'AccountsCount' as ab from accounts..account
union all
select count(*) amount, 'PlayersCount' as ab from players..player
)
select * 
from value as s
PIVOT(sum(nbr) for name in (AccountsCount, PlayersCount) ) as pvt
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code solves the question. This will help the OP learn from your answer as well as future searchers.